# How can I make my balcony safe for my cat?

Tags: cats, safety, containment

My cat enjoys hanging out on the balcony and likes to jump up on the railing. The problem is that my railing is fairly thin, curved on top, and made of smooth plastic -- making it difficult for my cat to balance (she's a bit clumsy in general, too). She occasionally wobbles a bit when trying to walk along the railing, and a couple times she has almost slipped and had to cling on to save herself. Needless to say this makes me extremely nervous, and I've started letting her outside less (only when I can be right there with her). She's very sad about that and regularly sits at the sliding door crying to be let out. I'm not sure how dangerous a fall would actually be (I live on the 4th floor of an apartment building), but I don't want to find out.

Is there any way to either:

1. prevent her from jumping up on the railing, or
2. make it safe for her to be up on the railing?

What I have in mind is something that could be attached to the railing that would either block her from jumping on it or provide a flat walkway that she could walk on instead of the railing itself. However, I have no idea what might work.

Comment: I prefer your second approach, and also you could build a 2ft wide net on the perimeter of your balcony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a cat tree on the balcony?  If not, this may at least be a partial solution.   I used to have a cat that did the same thing.  Your kitty wants to be up high so she can see everything.  Get a cat tree, with several levels, that is taller than the railing.  Of course, place it somewhere away from the railing so she can't jump from the tree to the railing.  This won't completely stop the behavior but should greatly reduce it.

My kitty (that also climbed on the railing) did fall.  We were only on the second floor.  One day, I went to check on her, and she wasn't there.  I was frantic.  I put up flyers with her picture on everyone's apartment door.  Two long days later, someone found her hiding in the bushes one building away.  Thankfully, she was not hurt.  Stories like these don't always have a happy ending.

Knowing what I know now, I would probably put a cat enclosure on the balcony to be sure my kitty didn't fall.   Take a look at these:

[cat cages and playpens](http://www.wayfair.com/Cat-Cages-and-Enclosures-C409570.html)

[grand prix enclosure](http://www.teampetsupply.com/cat-enclosures/2793-kittywalk-grand-prix-outdoor-cat-enclosure.html)

[custom cat enclosures](http://www.cagesbydesign.com/t-suncatchercat.aspx)

Spend whatever money is necessary to keep your kitty safe.  You'll have peace of mind, which is worth a lot more.  ... And next time you get a cat, make sure the kitty never knows there is an outside.

Answer (score 3):

Some people surround their balconies with netting.  However, the cat will climb the net, guaranteed! Provided it's strong and well-secured, this shouldn't be a problem, and it leaves you with a bit of a view of the outdoors. Alternatively, you might be able to find some clear plastic sheeting that would be thick enough to be claw-proof.

While there are ways to discourage the cat from jumping up onto the railing, I wouldn't put my confidence in them given the danger.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion. Cats do what cats do. Just build a safe place on the deck the cat can hangout safely. Instinct will do the rest.

Comment: i think this answer need more information.